# Unable to generate og:image

Tags: media, meta-tags

I have installed the Metatag module, along with ImageCache Token, but it just does not work.

I have tried many of the different available tokens in the Open Graph image field for my node, and none of them generate a og:image tag. For instance, I have tried:

[node:my_image]
[node:my_image:large:path]
[node:my_image:large]
[node:my_image:thumbnail]

if I hard-code a URL rather than use a token then it works, but that rather defeats the purpose. My logs contain no errors, and I remember to clear the cache each time. This is driving me nuts. Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the [imagecache_token](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_token) module? After having enabled that it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I did (sorry I put "ImageCache" instead of "imagecache_token" in my post above).

Comment: I'm also having this exact issue. The error on the facebook debug console https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ is `og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.` I have a hunch that that this has to do with the security vulnerability addressed in Drupal 7.20 and 7.21 where all image styles add a token to the url, to prevent DoS attacks, but not sure.

Comment: Have you tested on the Facebook debug page as mentioned by @JamesWilson?

Comment: This https://www.drupal.org/node/2631408 or this https://www.drupal.org/node/2667850 may be the issue. Hopefully they push out a release soon.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your image has **at least 200x200** as defined in the error provided by Facebook debugger.
Also use **Ctrl+U** in your browser to check that the **og:image** tag print the correct url